# Generate a deck of cards in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently trying to build a program which predicts odds of winning with various starting hands in poker. I figure that the best way to represent each `Card` is by making it an object with two properties: `number` and `suit`. I figure I should then add this to an array called `deck` - but I'm not sure what the best way to generate this deck of cards is? I could type them all out - or I could make a `for loop` which calls the `Card` constructor 52 times, but is there a better way...?

Comment: Your last suggestion sounds solid to me. Just make sure you don't repeat any cards and you're golden.

Comment: Generating them with loops sounds good to me.

Comment: Probably two loops. One for each suit, one for each number.

Comment: a foreach loop i think will be a better solution..

Comment: Does your deck need to be in random order?

Comment: @SNash Yes, but I figured I could randomise the array after the cards are added.

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun, because I'm just a little weird that way, I built a little javascript that creates the cards and then displays them in random order.  I did use jQuery but it's not necessary

First define the suits, the card numbers, and the cards array that will store the cards.  The count variable is for tracking which card to display on the screen next.

```
var suits = ["H","S","C","D"];
var numbers = ["A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K"];
var cards = [];
var count = 0;
```

Add a shuffle and draw button and a place to display the cards

```
<button id="shuffle">Shuffle</button>
<button id="draw">Draw</button>

<div id="cards"></div>
```

Now the meat of the function, generating and shuffling the cards

On the shuffle button's click event, I run two for loops that generates the cards and assigns a random number to the card.  The card object created, stores the suit, the number and a random number between 1 and 5200. I chose a big number to minimize the chances of getting a duplicate number

```
$("#shuffle").click(function() {
    count = 0
    cards = [];
    $("#cards").html("");
    for(s in suits) {
        var suit = suits[s];
        for(n in numbers) {
            var num = numbers[n]
            var card = {
              suit: suit,
              number: num,
              order: Math.floor(Math.random() * 5200) + 1   
            };
            cards.push(card);   
        }
    }
```

To sort the cards, you can use a custom sort function.

```
    cards = cards.sort(function(a,b) {
        return (a.order < b.order ? -1 : 1)
    });
```

Finally, display the first four from the deck

```
    for(var i = 0;i < 4;i++) {
        count++;
        dispCard(i);
    }
});
```

I used a function called dispCard to display the card

```
function dispCard(cardNum) {
    var i = cardNum
    var count = cardNum + 1;
    var card = cards[i];
    $("#cards").append(count + " - " + card.number + card.suit + "<br/>");   
}
```

The draw button just takes the next card, and does nothing if the number is 52

```
$("#draw").click(function() {
    if(count < 52) {
        dispCard(count);
        count++;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Here's a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/robbertv/0vckmfLq/)